# Pull Data from Excel Worksheet to Another Based on Defined Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have two excel worksheets which have data cells. I want that if a cell in column J equals a certain value, let's saying "Negotiating", then it automatically pulls that row to a new worksheet.

The idea being that I can see a list of the most relevant rows I need from across all my worksheets.

Comment: So if for example, cells J21 & J23 both contain "Negotiating", you want to copy all cells in rows 21 & 23 to another worksheet, displayed in rows 2 & 3 (or 1 & 2) ?

Comment: You shouls use the Advanced Filter which allows you to copy filtered data to another location easily. See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/656762/25261

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic copy rows with matched column to other worksheet](http://superuser.com/questions/656694/automatic-copy-rows-with-matched-column-to-other-worksheet)